# Framer Motion onDrag behaviour

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I want to recreate the example of this modal closing via `onDrag` in Framer Motion v1 but in the latest version of Framer Motion.

Here, in version 1 of Framer Motion, `onDrag` behaves as expected... once the `onDrag` function is called the animation completes and the element returns to it's original position.

**v1, expected behaviour:** https://codesandbox.io/s/framermotion-v1-ondrag-4x2n7j?file=/src/Card.tsx

But in the latest package (10.x) with onDrag the closing animation is not run (it just jumps to the end?) and it moves the element down the page. However, using onDragEnd with the latest package it does do these things again, but obvioulsy the drag needs to be released first, which is not the desired behaviour.

**v10.x, current behaviour:** https://codesandbox.io/s/framermotion-ondrag-wjlr7r?file=/src/Card.tsx

As per [the official changelog in the Framer Motion docs](https://www.framer.com/motion/guide-upgrade/##breaking-changes) at v2 the `onDrag` had breaking changes, but this behaviour still should be available somehow?